# Behaviour after scroll event

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a problem using Angular2. If I'm not mistaken in Angular2 I should put my code in class instead of controller and access variables by `this` but I have a variable I want to access from function assigned to `window.onscroll`, and `this` inside this function doesn't work, because it return `window`.

How can I access my variables or functions on scroll event?

```
class someClass{

    someVariable;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.someVariable = {}; 

        window.onscroll = function() {

            // here I want to access someVariable or someFunction

        }
    }

    someFunction() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several way to do that:

1) Using **HostListener**:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll() {
  console.log(this.someVariable);
}
```

2) Using **arrow function**:

```
window.onscroll = _ => {
  console.log(this.someVariable);
};
```

3) Using of **Function.prototype.bind()**:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  console.log(this.someVariable);
}.bind(this);
```

4) Keep context in a variable like **self** or **that**:

```
let self = this;
window.onscroll = function() {
  console.log(self.someVariable); // <== notice self instead of this
};
```