# How to show original image dimensions in Angular 2 template?

Tags: image, angular

I have a simple requirement to show the *original* dimensions of a given image URI. Something very simple like this.

```
<div><img src="{{imageUri}}"/></div>
<p>Image size: {{width}}x{{height}}</p>
```

I'm using the asynchronous approach to getting the image dimensions by [listening for the "load" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images). But in the event handler how can I update the UI?

I've tried to simply set `this.width` and `this.height` in my component, which implements `OnInit`. The snippet below illustrates what I'm trying to do, and I also created a [more complete plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/DCSfx8sj7CLoMSCZ2HJG?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem.

```
constructor() {
  this.imageUri = 'https://angular.io/resources/images/logos/angular2/angular.svg';
  this.width = 0;
  this.height = 0;
}

handleImageLoad(event): void {
  this.width = event.target.width;
  this.height = event.target.height;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.version = 2;  // Just to prove Angular is working

  // Set the image height and width
  var image = new Image();
  image.addEventListener('load', this.handleImageLoad);
  image.src = this.imageUri;
}
```

I feel like there's a very simple solution that I'm missing, or some tenet of Angular 2 that I'm unintentionally violating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrow function to retain context:

```
image.addEventListener('load', (e) => this.handleImageLoad(e));
```

See also [Behaviour after scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634983/behaviour-after-scroll-event/37635129#37635129)

Comment: That's magical, yurzui. I don't know why this works but it does, and I will figure out the reason later. Thank you!

Comment: You can take a look at the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this